# Best practice Docker volumes on Windows

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I'm running Windows 10 and I'd like to mount some of the directories of my host into docker containers using docker-compose.

So say I have a folder with pictures:
`D:\MyPictures`

I want to create a volume in Docker, and mount that volume into different containers to be able to access the pictures.
Preferable I only have to define my volume once so that I can refer to it by name or similar (in case I want to move the picture folder in the future, I only have one place to update the path).
And it would also be nice if I can, per container, specify if the container has read/write access or just read access.

I know how I can do it if I specify the volume directly under a service:

```
myservice:
  volumes:
    - /c/MyPictures:/mount/path/in/container
```

But then if I move my pictures I'd have multiple places to update the path.

And when reading about creating volumes with `docker volume create` it looks as if I can't specify read/write access per container then.

What would be the best and easiest way of achieving this on Windows?

- Specify a volume once
- Mount it in different containers
- Access granularity per container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Best answer (found by orderlyfashion) :**

Use an env variable.

1. Create a file `globals.env` with the variable `MY_PICTURES=/c/MyPictures`
2. In `docker-compose.yml`, under the volume section for the container, mount as: `- ${MY_PICTURES}:/my_pictures:ro`
3. Start with `docker-compose --env-file global.env up`

---

If you create a volume with `docker volume create`, you can then specify it in the top-level `volume`section of compose, and then use the name of the volume followed by the path and the access rights in each container, you are not stopped from specifying the access.

See more [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volumes), specifically

> The short syntax uses the generic [SOURCE:]TARGET[:MODE] format, where SOURCE **can be either a host path or volume name.** TARGET is the container path where the volume is mounted. Standard modes are ro for read-only and rw for read-write (default).

---

The next problem when doing that is that named volumes cannot be bound to a specific folder, contrary to bind mounts.

When you do a `-v <hostPath>:<containerPath>` you create a bind-mount. It is a specific folder from the host filesystem that is mounted in the container filesystem, all good, but it has a downfall : it cannot be shared.

When you add the `volumes` top level option or do a `docker volume create`, you create a named volume. A named volume is a space that can be shared across containers, but cannot be bound to a specific folder on your host. But if you write data to this volume, it stays in it, it is a persistent volume.

So the question is : how to initialize this volume with data ? And the answer is to mount that volume in a container that will write the data in the volume. It is not graceful, and a bit convoluted, but that is the solution ...

How to do that :

In you docker-compose.yml, add this service and volume :

```
services:
  initializer:
    image: <someimage> #I use python:3.9-slim, could be a simple busybox
    command: cp -R /mnt/. /media/
    volumes:
      - ./somefolder:/mnt
      - data_volume:/media
    service_you_want_to_attach_volume_to:
      ...
      volumes:
        - data_volume:<some path>:ro #or rw, you can set the rights per container
      depends_on:
        - initializer

volumes:
  data_volume:
```

The container initializer will launch, mount the folder with the data you want in /mnt, mount the named volume in /media, copy the data from /mnt *(so the data you want to share)* to /media *(the named volume to share it)* and then stop *(because it has finished its main process)*

The named volume is now initialized and can be shared to any container with the access rights (`ro` or `rw`) that you want.

**UPSIDES** : Everything is in a docker volume, easy to backup
**DOWNSIDES** : Data **will be** duplicated inside the volume. You will get twice the same amount of data, and the data will not be updated unless you redo an initialization

Comment: Okay. So there are three steps. 1) `docker volume create`. 2) List volume in docker-compose. 3) Refer to volume in service config in docker-compose.
What I'm not understanding is, where do I specify the path on my host machine?

For step 1 it says `The built-in local driver on Windows does not support any options.`, so I don't see how I specify the path there.
For step 2 I've tried `my-pictures://c/MyPictures`, `my-pictures://c/MyPictures:/my-pictures` and a bunch of different things, but it's all invalid.

Comment: Sorry it took so long, I explained the process in my answer

Comment: Sorry, I got an idea and didn't have time to test it until now.
I came up with another solution by using variables.
1) Create a file `globals.env` with the variable `MY_PICTURES=/c/MyPictures`. 
2) In `docker-compose.yml`, under the volume section for the container, mount as: `- ${MY_PICTURES}:/my_pictures:ro`. 
3) Start with `docker-compose --env-file global.env up`. That seems to fulfil my requirements and worked. 

Do you see any problems with this approach? In your solution, is the data duplicated somehow? I'm not sure I understand how the copy step works exactly.

Comment: Your solution is great :) In my solution, a container is created and the volume is mounted in it. The data is then duplicated into this volume. After that, the volume can be shared by multiple containers (no data duplication) . It's a lot more costly than a simple variable !

Comment: Okay. So if I understand it correctly I see two downsides with your solution, depending on use case. 1) The data is duplicated. If I have 50 GB of pictures, now I also have an additional 50 GB volume on top of the actual pictures. 2) Any changes I make to my original folder is not replicated into the volume until I re-create the container.
Either you modify your answer with both solutions and some information about the difference, or I can do it. Then I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I've created a volume in a Linux container in advance and then tried to mounting it through the docker compose.

Defining it with the usual way like:

```
volumes:
  data_volume:
```

It failed in the sense that it didn't reuse the same volume I've created in advance but it created a new volume, but my goal was to reuse the other one where I already stored some data.

The solution was to inspect the volume I've created:

```
docker volume inspect data
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2024-03-22T15:58:06Z",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": null,
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/data/_data",
        "Name": "data",
        "Options": null,
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

Now in the docker compose file I can refer my volume using the `Mountpoint`:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  linuxbackend:
    network_mode: bridge
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - C:\\:/workspaces
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /var/lib/docker/volumes/data/_data:/mnt/data
```